# C# enums and booleans - looking for a more elegant way

Tags: c#, enums

I have an class which has a enum property and a boolean property, based on that it calls a specific method with specific parameters. I use a switch statement for the enum and an if for the boolean within each case of the switch. It is a long list and doesn't feel to me to be the most elegant solution. Anyone got a more elegant or simpler way to implement this?

```
            switch (ReadDecision)
            {
                case ReadDecisions.ReadNext:
                    {
                        if (UseTimeout)
                        {
                            Message = queue.Receive(Timeout);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Message = queue.Receive();
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                case ReadDecisions.PeekNext:
                    {
                        if (UseTimeout)
                        {
                            Message = queue.Peek(Timeout);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Message = queue.Peek();
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                case ReadDecisions.ReadMessageId:
                    {
                        if (UseTimeout)
                        {
                            Message = queue.ReceiveById(Id, Timeout);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Message = queue.ReceiveById(Id);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                case ReadDecisions.PeekMessageId:
                    {
                        if (UseTimeout)
                        {
                            Message = queue.PeekById(Id, Timeout);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Message = queue.PeekById(Id);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                case ReadDecisions.ReadCorrelationId:
                    {
                        if (UseTimeout)
                        {
                            Message = queue.ReceiveByCorrelationId(Id, Timeout);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Message = queue.ReceiveByCorrelationId(Id);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                case ReadDecisions.PeekCorrelationId:
                    {
                        if (UseTimeout)
                        {
                            Message = queue.PeekByCorrelationId(Id, Timeout);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Message = queue.PeekByCorrelationId(Id);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Unknown ReadDecisions provided");
                    }
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An often used convention is that a timeout of zero means no timeout. Maybe you could drop the UseTimeout (property?) and use the value zero instead. That'd eliminate some stuff.

Comment: In this scenario a timeout of 0 means inifinity... which supposedly a possible scenario it must cater for.

Comment: An infinity timeout is the same as not using a timeout though isn't it? So if you use zero for both cases you don't need the UseTimeout bool property.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on what `queue` is, could you change the signature of `Peek()` and `Peek(bool)` to `Peek(bool?)`? (The rest of the methods should follow as well.)

That way, instead of:

```
if (UseTimeout)
{
    Message = queue.Peek(Timeout);
}
else
{
    Message = queue.Peek();
}
```

you could have:

```
Message = queue.Peek(UseTimeout ? Timeout : null);
```

The other idea is you could push the decision structure to the queue class:

```
if(UseTimeout)
    Message = queue.PerformAction(ReadDecision, Timeout)
else
    Message = queue.PerformAction(ReadDecision)
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace the enum with classes:
http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceTypeCodeWithClass.html

You might also want to take a look at the Strategy pattern:
http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternStrategy.aspx

Comment: There are plenty of situations where simple enums are just what you need. It's when you start noticing the code smell of many switch statements on the enum in your code that you start needing to replace them with classes.

Comment: Yes, you're quite right- replacing the enum with six classes just to eliminate this switch statement would be overkill.

Answer (score 3):

The pattern I'm seeing here is a lot of method pairs named foo(ID) and foo(ID, timeout). In your situation I would:

- Create a third kind of method `foo(ID, timeout, bool useTimeout)`, by merging the bodies of  `foo(ID)` and `foo(ID, timeout)`.
- Change `foo(ID)` to call `foo(ID, null, false)` and `foo(ID, timeout)` to call `foo(ID, timeout, true)`
- Change your switch statement to always call `foo(ID, Timeout, UseTimeout)`.
- Repeat the above for each applicable pair of methods.

By doing this you've moved the flag that controls the usage of timeouts closer to where it actually needs to be used.

Answer (score 2):

I like Scott's suggestion to have a zero timeout mean no timeout. That would result in the following code, which is much more readable, but doesn't involve creating any extra classes. OTOH, if you've got this same switch statement anywhere else in your code, I'd go for the enum->classes refactoring.

```
switch (ReadDecision)
 {
  case ReadDecisions.ReadNext:
   {
    Message = queue.Receive(Timeout);
    break;
   }
  case ReadDecisions.PeekNext:
   {
    Message = queue.Peek(Timeout);
    break;
   }
  case ReadDecisions.ReadMessageId:
   {
    Message = queue.ReceiveById(Id, Timeout);
    break;
   }
  case ReadDecisions.PeekMessageId:
   {
    Message = queue.PeekById(Id, Timeout);
    break;
   }
  case ReadDecisions.ReadCorrelationId:
   {
    Message = queue.ReceiveByCorrelationId(Id, Timeout);
    break;
   }
  case ReadDecisions.PeekCorrelationId:
   {
    Message = queue.PeekByCorrelationId(Id, Timeout);
    break;
   }
  default:
   {
    throw new Exception("Unknown ReadDecisions provided");
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a Dictionary containing the enum as a Key and the Actions you do as a Value:

```
Dictionary<ReadDecisions,YourAction> decisions = new
           Dictionary<ReadDecisions,YourAction>();

decisions[ReadDecisions.ReadNext] = queue.Receive;
decisions[ReadDecisions.PeekNext] = queue.PeekById;
// you understand the main idea
//....
```

then replace your switch with:

```
if(UseTimeout)
   decisions[ReadDecision](id, Timeout);
else
   decisions[ReadDecision](id, 0);  //or another value 
                                    //telling you there is no timeout .
                                    // it just have to be the same signature
```

the only problem is that you have to have all the methods with the same signature.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a hashtable of delegates where the key would be the combination of ReadDecision and UseTimeout?
I have a feeling 'm asking for a downvote here...

Answer (score 0):

Why not simplify the parameters passed

```
int? optionalTimeout = UseTimeout ? Timeout : null;

switch (ReadDecision) {
    case ReadDecisions.ReadNext:
        Message = queue.Receive( optionalTimeout ); break;

    case ReadDecisions.PeekNext:
        Message = queue.Peek( optionalTimeout ); break;

    // and so on ...
```

Then in your queue method handle a null value passed for the `Timeout` as "don't timeout"

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest the following :

**1] The 'pair' methods can be grouped together**

Each of the individual should be able to handle NULL value. So you will have the following two groups:

```
Queue.Peek(TimeOut)
Queue.Receive(TimeOut)

Queue.ReceiveById(Id, TimeOut)
Queue.PeekById(Id, TimeOut)
...
```

**2] Declare two delegates for the method groups**

```
delegate Message MethodType1(Timeout)
delegate Message MethodType2(Id, TimeOut)
```

**3] Have a GetDelegate() method that would return the appropriate method to execute**

```
object GetDelegate(ReadDecisions param)
{
 switch(param)
 {

   case ReadNext:
             MethodType1 receiveDlgt = new MethodType1(queue.Receive);
   case PeekMessageId:
             MethodType2 peekDlgt = new MethodType2(queue.Peek);
   ...
 }
}
```

**4] Make the appropriate call depending on delegate type**

```
InvokingMethod()
{
  object methodToExecute = GetDelegate(ReadDecision)
  if (methodToExecute.GetType() == typeof(MethodType1)) 
    {
    methodToExecute(TimeOut)
    }
    else
    {
    methodToExecute(Id, TimeOut)
    }

}
```

Hope this helps. 
Some parts may need refining as per good programming practices.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to read the q like you are doing. Maybe refactor the thing to use a callback  ? 
MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue(queuePath);
// event handler
queue.ReceiveCompleted += QueueMessageReceived;  // name of method that gets called 
// start "listening" for messages
 queue.BeginReceive();

Answer (score -1):

What you've got looks fine to me. It's understandable to read, I'd feel confident maintaining it. There's no need to go fancy-shmancy on it.

For example, using a fancy pattern as suggested by somebody else about using classes instead of your enum would probably result in a new class for each case statement, and they'd probably go into a file each, and you'd need another file for the base interface... and this would be a heck of a lot of stuff. I don't know how anybody could justify this heck of a lot of stuff as a simpler way to express what you've already done quite a good job of.

Comment: Why the downvote! Is it because this doesn't agree with something you read in a text-book?

Comment: @DrJokepu: thanks mate! you've restored some of my confidence in my fellow stackoverflowiens. I'm am still hopeful for an upvote though from somebody who agrees this is useful advice :)

Comment: Hey! I got an upvote. The answers still negative, but upvoter person, you made my day!

Comment: I voted this one down because the question was to provide a simpler or more elegant way to implement it not to justify it needed to be done at all. I voted your other answer up because it did answer the question.

Comment: This is like a sisyphean struggle: no matter how many of us upvote your answer, there are always twice as many who will vote it down

Comment: I think the code really could do with simplfying, although if this is the only place where a decision is made based on that enum then I agree that adding six classes just to simply this one routine is overkill, which is why I upvoted your "zero timeout = no timeout" suggestion - velegant.

Comment: Thanks Robert. It's always nice to know the reasons behind a downvote. I hope you get the code arranged into a way you think is elegant. I suppose everybody's got a different idea of what is elegant. Many questioners aren't quite sure what questions to ask.. I thought this may have been useful info.

Comment: +1 Just because an answer is asking for a specific solution doesn't mean someone can't suggest an alternative solution. If that's the case then we're going to be answering questions based on the asker's expectations rather than presenting alternatives which may be just as valid.